# get confused about the object, why I can not just use obj to getIdStr() instead of making a new personObj

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a my own equals method. But I'm confused about the obj in the code. In the part of equals method I must create a new personObj, in which way I can use getIdStr. Why I can not just use obj like obj.

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private String idStr;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String idStr) {
        this.name = name;
        this.idStr = idStr;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setIdStr(String idStr) {
        this.idStr = idStr;
    }

    public String getIdStr() {
        return idStr;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("" + obj);
        System.out.println("" + this);

        if (this == obj)

            return true;
        if (obj != null && obj.getClass() == Person.class) {

            Person personObj = (Person) obj;
            System.out.println("" + obj.getClass());
            System.out.println("" + personObj.getClass());
            if (this.getIdStr().equals(personObj.getIdStr())) {
                return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
}


public class OverrideEqualsRight {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person("ur sister", "121");
        Person p2 = new Person("ur brother", "121");
        Person p3 = new Person("ur mon", "122");
        System.out.println("p1 equals p2?" + p1.equals(p2));
        System.out.println("p2 equals p3?" + p1.equals(p3));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only comparing the ID of each person so `p1.equals(p2)` return `true` because `p1` and `p2` both have the same ID 121 in your test.  Is that your problem?

Comment: You don't have to create a new reference, you can use `((Person)obj).getIdStr()` instead. A new reference makes the code easier to read though.

Comment: Also `System.out.println("p2 equals p3?" + p1.equals(p3));` is not doing what it says!

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` method accepts `Object`, not `Person`. `Object` class doesn't have `getIdStr()` method. In other words - you do really work with `Person`, but initially it is represented like `Object`, so you need to cast it to `Person` first.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't "creat[ing] a new" personObj, but rather creating a variable named "personObj" that references the existing "obj" but is aware of its more specific runtime type "Person". This conversion is necessary, because the type Object does not have the functionality of Person (i.e. getIdStr() is  a function that exists on Person, but not on Object), so to use it, you must know that the object you are dealing with has a type with a method matching that signature. The statement "Person personObj = (Person) obj" is doing what is called a "cast", which is validating that the variable "obj" is of type "Person" and providing you another view of this very same object but with this more specific type information available to it.